# How do I retrieve a URL from a web site using Java?

Tags: java, http, url, connection

I want to use HTTP GET and POST commands to retrieve URLs from a website and parse the HTML. How do I do this?

Comment: Use http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

Comment: I have used [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) in a project and it worked quite well.
A list of other parsers is [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers), but besides from JTidy I don't know any of them.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [HttpURLConnection](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) in combination with [URL](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html).

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();

InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
// read the contents using an InputStreamReader
```

Comment: Thank you. This shows the most basic way to do it. It's simple with an understanding of what's necessary to do a simple URL connection. However, the longer term strategy would be to use [HTTP Client ](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/index.html "HTTP Client") for more advanced and feature rich ways to complete this task.

Comment: Create a BufferedReader using the InputStream to read the content into a string variable

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do a GET is to use the built in java.net.URL. However, as mentioned, httpclient is the proper way to go, as it will allow you among others to handle redirects.

For parsing the html, you can use [html parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/).