# How to download xml data of a website?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have searched about this. All I got was xml parsing/ Sax parser. I need a program that will download xml data.
I need this for my android application development. thanks

For example i have a website localhost:8080/folder/sample.html.. How do i get a .xml file from that?

Comment: If you got url of that xml, get the stream using http client.

Comment: Well i am getting my own website xml data. So its localhost:8080

Comment: It must provide some url right like localhost:8080/project/myfile.xml

Comment: Hmm correct but not what i am looking for. For example i have this website localhost:8080/folder/sample.jsp how do i get a .xml file from that?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if I'm not answering the question - but is it the website content, you want to download? If positive, these are similar questions where the solution may lie:

- [How to get a web page's source code from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616781/how-to-get-a-web-pages-source-code-from-java)
- [Get source of website in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422970/get-source-of-website-in-java)
- [How do I retrieve a URL from a web site using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359439/how-do-i-retrieve-a-url-from-a-web-site-using-java)
- [How do you Programmatically Download a Webpage in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238547/how-do-you-programmatically-download-a-webpage-in-java)
- [A good library to do URL Query String manipulation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218608/a-good-library-to-do-url-query-string-manipulation-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

try this code:

```
public String getXmlText(String urlXml) {
    URL url;
    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedReader br;
    String line;
    String result = null;

    try {
        url = new URL(urlXml);
        is = url.openStream();
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            result = result + line + "\n";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    } finally {
        try {
            if (is != null) is.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {}
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class Crawle {

    public static void main(String ar[]) throws Exception {

        URL url = new URL("http://www.foo.com/your_xml_file.xml");
        InputStream io = url.openStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(io));
        FileOutputStream fio = new FileOutputStream("file.xml");
        PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(fio, true);
        String data = "";
        while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {

            pr.println(data);
        }


    }
}
```