# HttpClient in java

Tags: java, http, httpclient

I want to use a simple HttpClient.

However, it appears `sun.net.www.http.HttpClient` is inaccessible.

Also, `com.ibm.ws.http.HTTPConnection` - appears to be more supporting of http server and not client. Why? Because when I create an instance of HttpConnection, it has a "getHttpResponse" to which I am supposed to write.

Anyway to use the IBM HttpConnection for HttpClient?

Or, is there any standard httpClient code that I can use?

Comment: https://github.com/square/okhttp is a good and popular one. Very well maintained

Comment: FYI: Java 11+ has a new HTTP client implementation built-in. See [*JEP 321: HTTP Client*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/321).

Answer (score 20):

Many people use [Apache's HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/).

Have a look at the first few chapters of [its tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/index.html) to see if it's what you're looking for.

If you're after something simple that's already built into Java, you can look at [HttpURLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), which you can use to build HTTP requests ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359439/how-do-i-retrieve-a-url-from-a-web-site-using-java/360291#360291)). If you need to do anything more than just simple HTTP requests, though, HTTPClient is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 18):

I highly recommend [Unirest](http://unirest.io/java.html):

```
Unirest.post("http://httpbin.org/post")
  .queryString("name", "Mark")
  .field("last", "Polo")
  .asString()
```

Comment: Unirest & jcabi-http (as suggested by @yegor256) seem to be the 2 most easy to use library, and the usage are pretty similar. Do you guys know any different between the two?

Comment: Those static methods are a pain when it comes to unit testing. I'm considering replacing Unirest with OkHttp in my project as I could pass in a mocked OkHttpClient object then (instead of using PowerMock as of now). Also, OkHttp comes with a MockWebServer for integration testing.

Comment: I think this is most easy to use client

Answer (score 3):

There is another option in using [google-http-java-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/).

This library provides a simple and flexible API together with a pluggable approach to use low-level HTTP libraries like java.net.HttpURLConnection or Apache HTTP Client.

Sample code for posting content to content from an InputStream to a specific URL:

```
HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = HTTP_TRANSPORT.createRequestFactory();
InputStream is = ...;
URL url = new URL(...);
String contentType = ...;
HttpRequest httpRequest = requestFactory.buildPostRequest(
  new GenericUrl(url), new InputStreamContent(contentType, is)
);
HttpResponse execute = httpRequest.execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [Apache's HTTPClient fluent API](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fluent.html) it's so easy in use!

```
// Execute a GET with timeout settings and return response content as String.
Request.Get("http://somehost/")
    .connectTimeout(1000)
    .socketTimeout(1000)
    .execute().returnContent().asString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a third party class, just use java's own `URL` and `HttpURLConnection` classes.
See an example [here](http://agalaxyjava.blogspot.in/2014/12/simple-java-httpclient.html).

Comment: Sadly the above link is dead.