# Server to Server communication using servlet?

Tags: java, web-services, api, jsp, servlets

In my case there is a cloud server and personal application server.

I have to make a communication between both servers for accessing the data periodically.

How to create api for communication using servlet.

Is possible to use timer in servlet?

Any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will you application server fetch data from the server or the other way around? What time is it that you want to measure?

Comment: Yes my jsp application have to fetch data from the another server database. That fetching has to be happened periodically(with specific interval)

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430300/is-possible-to-do-background-process-in-jsp-using-timer?noredirect=1#comment41505502_26430300) . That question is an reflection of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can user a [timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java) within a servlet, but as Stanley suggested, [web services](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijti.html) is a layer on top of http that you can use and it may be easier.

If you just need some quick and dirty way, you can write a servlet [to receive the http request in one end](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm) and some [http client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051648/httpclient-in-java) to do the request.

If you go Java EE, it's even easier because you can generate web services using annotations and there's already a [TimerService](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html) so you won't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430300/is-possible-to-do-background-process-in-jsp-using-timer?noredirect=1#comment41505502_26430300) . That question is an reflection of this question.