# A J2EE server collect information of another server, possible?

Tags: jakarta-ee, restful-architecture

I'm doing a project. My teacher provides a server having Restful API, but it isn't for android app. I would like to develop another server (by J2EE) which can collect information of my teacher server (by using its Restful API) to provide a Restful API for my androi app.
It means that my server provides web service for my android app and it's also client of my teacher server.
That's my project idea. I wonder if it's possible with J2EE. If it's possible, how to send and receive HTTP messages by J2EE ?
Thank you very much in advanced for your answers.

Comment: In what way the REST API isn't compatible with an android app? Your idea is possible, but really unnecessary. Contact the teachers server directly.

Answer (score 0):

Being a client to another Restful HTTP service you must use an HTTP client and it isn't really relevant if your application (as client) is developed in a J2EE context or is a standalone console application.

The [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) is pretty common and allows you to create your GETs, POSTs, and other verbs directly. It also supports HTTPS and the typical authentication methods. Nevertheless this is a matter of preference and you can also check the answers to a question like [HttpClient in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6051648/4316023) for more opinions.